# in <new> SwiftUI 5.3 with no ViewControllers where do you override motion events

Tags: ios, swift

Typically in a ViewController - but in the new (5.3 & iOS 14) SwiftUI with declarative code... where does one put these methods?  It doesn't appear that one can just drop code into a view builder...

e.g.

```
 import CoreMotion

 override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
      if motion == .motionShake {'
         print ("SHAKE GESTURE DETECTED")
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer I got from Twitter's Majid Jabrayilov @mecid !! Thanks!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Shake Me!")
        MotionView(handler: {
            print(" - earthquake!")
        })
    }
}
```

Note that the 'MotionView' has no screen representation - but is a view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MotionView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = MotionViewController
    
    let handler: () -> Void
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MotionViewController {
        print("MotionView::makeUIViewController called.  Returning Controller with 'no-Op' handler.")
        
        return MotionViewController(handler: handler)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MotionViewController, context: Context) {
        print("updateUIViewController called...")
    }
}
```

Then behind that view is the controller... this controller overrides the motion events and injects our 'handler()' ... it's just the print statement in the demo.

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

final class MotionViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let handler: () -> Void
    
    init(handler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.handler = handler
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if motion == .motionShake {
            print("\t\tinside MotionViewController::motionEnded() shaken not stired.")
            handler()
        }
    }
}
```

The controller overrides the 'motionEnded' method and if it detects a shake event (predefined by Apple) calls our 'handler()'

I wonder if this style of injection / overriding is what the Swift designers intend with SwiftUI declarative coding??

Comment: check out @majid's site for more SwiftUI goodness https://swiftwithmajid.com

Comment: Want your mind blown - watch this 30 min video (Smarter Every Day #2) about the Saturn V rocket computers.  It's doing the same thing the iPhone's motion detector is doing - but with 1960s state of the art computer the size of a rocket ring.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mMK6iSZsAs